# Facebook - Have login in popup

Tags: php, facebook

Using the php sdk for the Facebook API access. When I get the login url and have the user click that to authorize access for my app is there anyway via php to have it done in a popup? I tried just a normal popup but all I get is the facebook logo. It will only work if I go straight to the page itself and not via popup. Is there a parameter to pass to tell it to prompt in a popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this via the FB JS-SDK and this Tag

```
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
```

Take a look at this example: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a regular javascript popup works. My original issue was it wasnt working with jquery colorbox. Though I prefer to use colorbox doesnt appear to allow this to work with facebook.